# How can I skip already loaded ckeditor.js and create a new editor instance by loading newer version of ckEditor.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, editor

My app acts as a plugin to other websites.It has a newer version of CkEditor with different set of config with ckeditor jquery adapter.

Issue is when my app gets loaded to a website which already has a ckeditor files loaded.

whenever I do a `$("#1").ckeditor();` where '#1' is jquery selector for textarea.

It loads editor from a already loaded ckeditor.js of the website (not the one which should load with my app).

How can I force to load that (the one present in my app) particular CkEditor ?

Comment: Can you make your app load inside a iframe on another website? that way all the scripts and css stuff will be local to your iframe and you will not get any conflicts

Comment: No I cannot. It will be a huge change too late to do that

Comment: Just a thought but never tried such things, Wrap your plugin in a Namespace and then you can initialize the plugin like may be `$("#1").YourNameSpace.ckeditor();`

Comment: Let me know if you need further help. I will make a JSFiddle for you

Comment: I just saw the plugin code .ckeditor() is the jquery extension method exposed by them. Going deep into plugin code I see ckEditor has a global variable window.CKEDITOR which is already prefilled with older editor values. As it is already prefilled object, when I try to load my ckeditor object it skips the whole series of steps.

Comment: Ok lets assume that we get around this scenario and make your ckEditor work. Are you sure this will not cause issues to the website loading your app?? As even the website will have its own editor and might have defined functionalities which might break.

Comment: I was thinking of modifying the plugin code(not the ideal way) 
instead of creating window.CKEDITOR I will modify the code in such a way it will create window.MYCKEDITOR object in that it wont conflict the previous editor.  This apprach is risky as I may break any of its functionality

Comment: worth a try. Please post back if it works for you